# Mathematical Induction with series and factorials.

Tags: sequences-and-series, induction, factorial

I wish to show the following

$$
a_{n}=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{1}{(2k+1)!(2(n-k)+1)!}=\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}\frac{1}{(2k)!(2(n+1-k))!}=b_{n+1}
$$

for $n\geq0$ and wish to do it using induction. I've shown it to be true when $n=0$, no issues there. But I'm running into all sorts of trouble when I wish to show $a_{m+1}=b_{m+2}$, assuming $a_{m}=b_{m+1}$ for some $m\geq0$.

I won't write down my scribblings here, as it would honestly just be super messy. My question is, can this be done using induction? And if not, is there a simple* method that will allow me to prove the result?

*as in, under-grad simple. I'm not equipped with a whole lot of fancy theorems.

My main attempt I will write down, in case it is on the right track or helpful in any way.

Using my inductive hypothesis, I can write
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=0}^{m}\frac{1}{(2k+1)!(2(m-k)+1)!}&=\sum_{k=0}^{m+1}\frac{1}{(2k)!(2(m+1-k))!}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{m}\frac{1}{(2k)!(2(m+1-k))!}+\frac{1}{(2(m+1))!}\\
\end{align*}
My idea with this was originally to get as much as I could under one summation, and I ended up with
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{m}\left[\frac{1}{(2k+1)!(2(m-k)+1)!}-\frac{1}{(2k)!(2(m+1-k))!}\right]=\frac{1}{(2(m+1))!}
$$
which became
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{m}\left[\frac{2(m-k)+2-(2k+1)}{(2k+1)!(2(m+1-k)!}\right]=\frac{1}{(2(m+1))!}
$$
and
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{m}\left[\frac{2m-4k+1}{(2k+1)!(2(m+1-k)!}\right]=\frac{1}{(2(m+1))!}
$$
but this seems way off-track. As I mentioned, I don't know whether this can be done using induction, but I'd *really like* it to be able to be. The RHS of the statement I wish to prove has that pesky $n+1$ term which also alters the summand. Because of this, I have no idea how to massage it to use my inductive hypothesis.

Here are some links to WolframAlpha also.

[When $n=0$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(sum+(1%2F((2k%2B1)!(2(0-k)%2B1)!))+from+k%3D0+to+0)+-+(sum+(1%2F((2k)!(2(1-k))!))+from+k%3D0+to+1))

[When $n=1$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(sum+(1%2F((2k%2B1)!(2(1-k)%2B1)!))+from+k%3D0+to+1)+-+(sum+(1%2F((2k)!(2(2-k))!))+from+k%3D0+to+2))

[When $n=2$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(sum+(1%2F((2k%2B1)!(2(2-k)%2B1)!))+from+k%3D0+to+2)+-+(sum+(1%2F((2k)!(2(3-k))!))+from+k%3D0+to+3))

[When $n=3$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(sum+(1%2F((2k%2B1)!(2(3-k)%2B1)!))+from+k%3D0+to+3)+-+(sum+(1%2F((2k)!(2(4-k))!))+from+k%3D0+to+4))

Any insight would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Does $$a_n = \frac{1}{(2n+2)!} \sum_{k = 0}^{n} \binom{2n+2}{2k+1}$$ help?

Comment: I didn't see this! I'll try it out and see. Thanks!

Comment: And use the binomial expansion for $(1-1)^{2n+2} = 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both $a_n$ and $b_{n}$ are given by convolutions:
$$\begin{array}{cclcl} a_n &=& \displaystyle\sum_{a+b=n}\frac{1}{(2a+1)!}\cdot\frac{1}{(2b+1)!} &=& \displaystyle[x^n]\left(\sum_{c\geq 0}\frac{x^c}{(2c+1)!}\right)^2 \\
 b_n &=& \displaystyle\sum_{a+b=n}\frac{1}{(2a)!}\cdot\frac{1}{(2b)!} &=& \displaystyle[x^n]\left(\sum_{d\geq 0}\frac{x^d}{(2d)!}\right)^2\end{array}\tag{1}$$
hence:
$$ a_n = [x^n]\left(\frac{\sinh \sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x}}\right)^2 = [x^n]\frac{\sinh^2(\sqrt{x})}{x} \tag{2}$$
as well as:
$$ b_n = [x^n]\left(\cosh(\sqrt{x})\right)^2 = [x^n]\cosh^2(\sqrt{x}) \tag{3}$$
and the claim ($a_n=b_{n+1}$) just follows from the identity $\cosh^2(z)-\sinh^2(z)=1$.

In a explicit way:
$$ a_n = [x^{n+1}]\sinh^2(\sqrt{x}) = [x^{2n+2}]\sinh^2(x) = \frac{2^{2n+1}}{(2n+2)!}, $$

$$ b_n = [x^{2n}]\cosh^2(x) = \frac{2^{2n-1}}{(2n)!}.\tag{4}$$

Comment: Haha, believe it or not, this is what sparked my question. I need to prove using power series that $\cosh^{2}(x)-\sinh^{2}(x)=1$, and as we haven't been given Cauchy product in class, I'm unable to use that for assessment. But thank you nonetheless!!

Comment: @Oldmate: for such a task, it is way easier to check for first that $$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\cosh^2(x)-\sinh^2(x)\right) = 0,$$ then evaluate $\cosh^2-\sinh^2$ at $0$.

Comment: @Oldmate: anyway, my $(4)$ now provides an explicit computation of $a_n$ and $b_n$ that does not require the identity $\cosh^2-\sinh^2=1$.

Comment: Thanks heaps - I didn't even consider differentiating.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^{2n+2}\frac{(-1)^k}{k!(2n+2-k)!}
=\frac{1}{(2n+2)!}\sum_{k=0}^{2n+2}(-1)^k{2n+2\choose k}
=\frac{1}{(2n+2)!}(1-1)^{2n+2}=0.
\end{align}